# How to make text Italic in description list?

Tags: italic, description

I want to have the first part of the text Italic.

This doesn't work (MWE):

```
\documentclass[pdftex]{scrreprt}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{mathpazo}

\begin{document}
    \begin{description}
        \item[5 V]\textit{(Pin: 2, 4)} rest of Text
    \end{description} 
\end{document}
```

How it should look:

> **5 V** *(Pin: 2, 4)* rest of Text

Why doesn't this work? And how do i get it to work?

**EDIT:** The problem was with `\usepackage{fontspec}`. The problem was solved with replacing `\usepackage{mathpazo}` with:

```
\setmainfont[
    BoldFont={Minion Pro Bold}, 
    ItalicFont={Minion Pro Italic},
    BoldItalicFont={Minion Pro Bold Italic}
]{Linux Libertine O}
```

Comment: You mean: *5 V* ?

Comment: it just works fine

Comment: @touhami: It should. But in my document \textit{} in the description doesn't do anything.

Comment: if it isn't italic then you have definitions that you have not shown that are changing the behaviour. Please always make the example a complete minimal document that shows the problem.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: You are right! The problem is based on my document font mathpazo.

Comment: do you get a latex message saying italic is not available in that font family? in any case please fix the example so that it demonstrates the problem.

Comment: No there was no error. But i made a MWE and found out the problem is not mathpazo but the problem is fontspec. The problem is solved. I have edited the post. Thanks for your hints.

Comment: I will close the question as it turned that the problem was somehow different than guessed in the question. Nice to see that it's solved.

Comment: @StefanKottwitz: That would be good. Thank you :)

Answer (score 2):

A quick way with `enumitem` and the `font` option.

Note: This way, **all** item description labels will be written in italic font.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{enumitem}

\begin{document}
\begin{description}[font={\itshape}]
    \item[5 V]\textit{(Pin: 2, 4)} rest of Text
\end{description} 
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer. "5 V" should only be bold and "(Pin: 2, 4)" only italic and the rest normal. The problem is that \\textit{} doesn't do anything in my document. The "(Pin: 2, 4)" still is normal and not italic

Comment: @Spen: Well, you did not provide a code to start with -- using a standard setup it works out of the box, as is expected from `\textit`

Comment: I just found out that it has something to do with my document font (mathpazo). It seems to not support italic. I will have to choose another font.